# I want SSIS to trap an error, branch and then exit with success

Tags: event-handling, ssis

I have googled around and think I have tried just about every suggestion I've seen but I can't seem to get this to work the way I want to.  I'm CONVINCED that SSIS can do this.

I have an SSIS package that has 4 tasks, they execute in order: task A, then B, then C.  The 4th task D I am using as an end-point if B fails... more on that in a minute.

Task A does some unrelated work.  I'm including it because there's processing at the start of the package and should any of it fail, then I want the package to fail - just the SSIS default, exit the package with a return code of 1 if task A fails.

B is a DFT with a flat-file source, it transfers data to be processed in step C.  B is the crux of my question because I want to deal with errors in task B differently than the rest.  It's not uncommon for the flat-file source to not exist or to be corrupt and I want to capture/trap that but not cause the entire package to fail.  If B does have an error though, I do NOT want to process task C.

C processes the data I transferred in DFT B when B does not have an error.

I am trapping errors in DFT-B with an "OnError" eventhandler that executes a SQL task that sends an email.  I then use an "on completion" precidence constraint to divert the control flow to an endpoint - task D.  (D does nothing, it's just a dummy end-point that I'm using partially for debugging, partially to give the event handler somewhere to "go" - I am not certain D is even required).

Anyway, when I run the package and trigger an error in B my package performs the event handler (sends the email just fine), it even continues on to task "D", and in the debugger, "D" ends with success (shows green).  The problem is, my package fails with an exit code of "1".

I've tried messing with all sorts of things... ForceExecutionValue/ ForceExecutionResult/ MaximumErrorcount.  Now I have a package that actually doesn't even contiune to my "task D" and I'm not sure how I got there (but the exception handler SQL is faithfully sending me an email!).

I do not want that exit code of 1!  I want a 0!

help!  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

[image: Conditional Flow]

To get the different conditions on the transition lines, just double click on the line you wish to edit. A red line indicates the control flow in case the previous task fails

**EDIT:** I believe i misread the question! From what i got, you can already control the flow as intended. Your issue comes with the exit code. Have you tried setting the `propagate` variable to false in the event handler screen?

Check the following link for more information on it:
http://simonworth.wordpress.com/2009/11/11/ssis-event-handler-variables-propagate/

Comment: Thank you so much, I did finally find the answer and you were right, I had the control flow correct.

Comment: Ack.  I'm still struggling.  I did get the desired behavior in a test package (thanks to some links I found on stackoverflow which led to another site, to another - and finally something that worked!).  But now that I tried to reproduce the logic in my production package (build the solution from scratch), it's not working!  So there is a very specific combination of settings.  I'll repost when I figure it out but I figure kudos for helping me and to this site for having other help.  At least I've made it work once, the rest is up to me!

Comment: your link ultimately is THE answer.  I was still having issues but they ultimately were sloppiness on my part.  So...kudos to you!  However, I can't give you a "thumb" (arrow?) up to mark the question answered by you - it says I don't have enough rep to do so!